# Magento 2 event observer call

Tags: rest-api

I have created one event for triggering an api on method "sales_order_shipment_save_after". But another 3rd party module is also triggering a same event but I want to call event of 3rd party module first and than call my module's event. 
Is it possible ? If yes so can you please guide me how ?

Answer (score 0):

And Make one module depends on another.

**Let's give an example:**

- `YourModule:` Observer class `YourModuleObserverClass`.
- `ThirdPartyModule:` Observer Class `ThirdPartyModuleObserverClass`.

You want  Call `YourModuleObserverClass` need to run after `ThirdPartyModule` .

So, please make  `YourModule` is module depends on `ThirdPartyModule`.

Add  `sequence` on `YourModule`'s `module.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="YourModule" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
        <!-- YourModule is dependent on ThirdPartyModule: -->
            <module name="ThirdPartyModule" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**After that don't forget run setup upgrade to apply these changes.**

I guess that it will resolve your issue.

Comment: okay let me check